# Return multiple <td> from map without wrapping them within an enclosed tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am sort of stuck in this case.
I know to solve this kind of errors we have to wrap them inside a container or something. But in this case I can't. Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

```
<div className="table-responsive col-lg-12">
  <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr className="active">
        <th className="width10">Name</th>
        <th className="width10">Number</th>
        <th className="width12">Email</th>
        <th className="width10">User Handle</th>
        <th className="width12">Address</th>
        <th className="width10">Device IMEI</th>
        <th className="width10">Mapped Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    { this.state.userDetails.map((user,i)=>{
        return(
          <tbody key={i}>
            <tr>
              <td>{user.fn ? user.fn : "-"}</td>
              <td>{user.mob ? user.mob : "-"}</td>
              <td>{user.eml ? user.eml : "NA"}</td>
              <td>{user.uh ? user.uh : "-"}</td>
              <td>{user.add ? user.add : "-"}</td>
            {this.state.deviceDetails.map((dev,i)=>{
              if(user.idx == dev.uid){
                return(
                  <td>{dev.imei ? dev.imei : "-"}</td>
                  <td>{dev.dm ? dev.dm : "-"}</td>
                )
              }
            })}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        )
      })
    }
  </table>
</div>
```

Above is my table which I want to render.
There are two arrays from which I have to show my table content.
So I have to perform mapping twice for both the different arrays.
When I map `this.state.userDetails` I got the error. If I wrap it inside a `<div>` or `<tr>` both the content will be placed in Device IMEI `<th>`. How can I solve this? Any help much appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping your content with a JSX sugar should work. You don't need to flatten the resulting array, React will do that for you.
See the  **[JSX Docs:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)**

```
  {this.state.deviceDetails.map((dev,i)=>{
          if(user.idx == dev.uid){
            return([
              <td>{dev.imei ? dev.imei : "-"}</td>,
              <td>{dev.dm ? dev.dm : "-"}</td>
            ])
          }
        })}
```

See **[this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127)** issue that is raised on React Github page.

Comment: Oop's I missed this there. But I can't find this thing in JSX Docs. 
Where did you got that? :/

Comment: I have added a link to Github issue. Have a look at that